# non axis aligned 3d bounding box (shape is a rectangle) collision detection

Tags: 3d, bounding-box

I am having trouble finding information about non axis aligned 3d bounding box collision detection.  I can find information about axis aligned collision detection in a 2d and 3d all day but 3d and non axis aligned is a much less common thing I guess.
If anyone can point me in the right direction i'd appreciate it.

THanks.

Comment: You convert the non axis aligned, into axis aligned in order to do detection.

Comment: Then maybe someone can explain the difference between axis aligned and non axis aligned?  How is this person able to successfully detect a collision when the boxes are not axis aligned?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GIwFyXB1h0

Comment: search for 'separating axis 3d box'